# Is it recommended to use color names, hex and RGB codes at the same time while naming colors in CSS?

Tags: css, colors, rgb

Does it matter if I use any type of coloring style while naming colors in CSS? For example, in this code can I mix these 3 types? I know that the results are all the same, I just need to know whether it's recommended or not while writing the clean code. Thank you.

```
border-color: #011082;
background-color: rgb(128,0,128);
color: white;
```

Comment: it's opinion based

Comment: Probably you should go with some CSS preprocessor (SASS/LESS/...) and use names there: you may define names of missing colours, and use functions (darken/lighten etc) to get derived colours. I prefer "black, white, red,.." on obvious places (where I expect I should not substitute if I change "theme"). Now some editors show you the colours, so HEX is not unreadable, but it is bad if you need to repeat yourself. Use a preprocessor.